# How to remove the Controller Name from Swagger Documentation methods

Tags: c#, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I am using Swashbuckle for having the Swagger documentation in my C# controller
If I have a controller as follows:

```
public class CommandController : ApiController
{
    public CommandResult Cancel(...)
    { ...}

    public CommandResult Status(...)
    { ...}

}
```

Then I can get the doc through http://localhost/swagger/ui/docs and I generate the doc in HTML or any other format, it will look as follows:

[image: REST API Docs]

In the above the commands on left side are are prefixed with the name of the controller.

Is there a way to remove the controller prefix and have only the name of the method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response (by NanoWar) to this GitHub issue seems to answer your question: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/6164

It involves adding a OperationFilter to your SwaggerConfig.

Comment: Great I'll test it and let you know the result.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar question and I just found it in official doc ([link](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/master/README.md))

> Option 2) Provide a custom strategy

```
// Startup.cs
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    ...

    // Use method name as operationId
    c.CustomOperationIds(apiDesc =>
    {
        return apiDesc.TryGetMethodInfo(out MethodInfo methodInfo) ? methodInfo.Name : null;
    });
})

// ProductsController.cs
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public IActionResult GetProductById(int id) // operationId = "GetProductById"
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add the `ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)` attribute.

Example:

```
namespace Example.Controllers;    
[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true), Route("[controller]")]
public class ExampleController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpDelete, Route("UndocumentedDeleteMethod")]
    public IActionResult UndocumentedDeleteMethod(int someId)
    { ... }
}
```

This assumes use of [Swashbuckle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone encountering issues with the swagger generated interfaces, models, or service names, [you may find this bash script helpful](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/7866#issuecomment-873355751), which pre-processes the swagger file, and post-processes the generated output files.